# Find computers in active directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

When I manually search for a computer using dsa.msc and open its properties, there is a "Location" tab. It might or might not have a value in it.
When I try to get this information using directory services of .Net, I do not see a "location" property. I printed out all available properties and don't see it. Is it just not available or am I missing something?
This is partial code:

```
string sADPath = "LDAP://blah.blah.com";
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(sADPath);

string sFilter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(name=" + sComputerName + "))";
DirectorySearcher DirectorySearch = new DirectorySearcher(de, sFilter);
SearchResult DirectorySearchResult = DirectorySearch.FindOne();

if (null != DirectorySearchResult)
{
    DirectoryEntry deComp = DirectorySearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
    oComputer.CN = deComp.Properties["cn"].Value.ToString();
    ....
}
```

---

**Edit:**

I misunderstood the requirment! It is not the "physical" location of the computer I need but where in the AD hierarchy it is. It seems that a computer that is supposed to be in "abc.org --> A --> B" is not there but is located in "abc.org --> A --> C --> D". What I need is to be able to find the path "abc.org --> A --> C --> D" given a computer name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The attribute name is 'location'.  As with all AD properties, you won't see it on a search result object if it doesn't have a value.  I've fiddled with your code so that it would just work on my machine.

If you're only retrieving data and not planning to make any changes you don't need to call GetDirectoryEntry (which will impose another round-trip to the servers).  Note the slight difference in syntax:

```
var rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");
var defaultNamingContext = rootDSE.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
var domainRootADsPath = String.Format("LDAP://{0}", defaultNamingContext);
var searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(domainRootADsPath);

var filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(name=" + computerName + "))";
var directorySearch = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot, filter);
var directorySearchResult = directorySearch.FindOne();

if (null != directorySearchResult)
{
    Console.WriteLine(directorySearchResult.Properties["cn"][0].ToString());
    if (directorySearchResult.Properties["location"].Count > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(directorySearchResult.Properties["location"][0].ToString());
    }

    //It's not necessary to run GetDirectoryEntry unless you want to make a change
    DirectoryEntry deComp = directorySearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
    Console.WriteLine(deComp.Properties["cn"].Value.ToString());
    if (deComp.Properties["location"].Value != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(deComp.Properties["location"].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried to get the "location" property but since it returned null I assumed there was no such property, especailly since listing all "computer" properties did not include "location". I did not take into consideration that "location" property might exist but not have a value in it (i.e. no location was defined for this computer). I will try to find a computer with a defined location and see if the "location" property actually returns something.

Comment: It does on my machine.  I populated it for my own computer, using ADU&C, to test the above code.

Comment: To find a machine with location, use this PowerShell:  `Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter '(&(objectClass=computer)(location=*))' -Properties location`

Comment: Thanks Simon.I just edited the post; it was my misunderstanding of the problem. What I need to find out (through .Net) is: given a computer name find it OU's hierarchy (e.g. from top; abc.org--> OU1 --> OU2 --> OU3, where OU2 is a node under OU1 and OU 2 is a node under OU2).

Comment: No problem: easily done.  Use the 'distinguishedName' attribute, instead of 'location'.  Or use the Path property on the DirectoryEntry.

Comment: Thank you Simon; "DistinguishedName" was what I needed. However, some computers show CN='computer_name' and a set of OU=... representing each node in AD; yet some others show CN='computer_name' CN='Computers' DC='abc' DC='def' DC='com', no OUs.

Comment: That's expected.  Most containers created in Active Directory are of the type 'organiationalUnit' but there are other types, such as 'container'.  CN=Computers is one of those.  In fact, computers and users can be containers as well: there's a switch in ADU&C to turn on the view that displays them.  I wouldn't, though, unless you need it as it makes things a bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run a search in all the results:

```
SearchResultCollection results = DirectorySearch.FindAll();
foreach(SearchResult res in results)
{
string[] temp = res.Path.Split(','); // temp[0] would contain the computer name
if(temp[0].Equals("...")) // ...
}
```

Or,try

```
string sFilter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(computerName=" + sComputerName + "))";
```

Replace "name" by "computerName"

Comment: I do get all the computer information including OS, service packs, dns hostname, etc., that is not the issue. But the computer properties I have access to do not seem to have a "Location" property whereas checking computer properties manually using dsa.msc, I see a "Location" tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find AD entry by host DNS name, try to use this:

```
using (var de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://domain.ru"))
        {
            var search = new DirectorySearcher(de, (string.Format("(dNSHostName={0})", hostName)));

            foreach (SearchResult i in search.FindAll())
            {
                return new MAdHost()
                    {
                        Name = hostName,
                        Path = i.Path
                    };
            }

        }
```