# Search for specific computer in AD

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to search my domain for a specific computer using C#. I have to search down a subtree which looks similar to the below example:

1. Company Computers

   - East
   - West
   - South

I have tried researching the issue but all the examples I find either look for a specific path, which I don't know, or search the entire domain.

I think I'm looking for the C# equivalent to Get-ADComputer.

Comment: That path is called DN (which consists of containers/OUs), and you can get that information from your system/AD Admin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find computers in active directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289306/find-computers-in-active-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following interactions of the MSDN C# forum, [cheong00](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/694d48a3-4723-423e-9026-743b7821badb/see-if-computer-exists-in-ad?forum=csharpgeneral) offered the below help:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;

    public static void FindComputer(string computerHostName)
    {
        DirectoryContext dirCtx = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, "domain.lan");
        using (Domain usersDomain = Domain.GetDomain(dirCtx))
        using (DirectorySearcher adsearcher = new DirectorySearcher(usersDomain.GetDirectoryEntry()))
        {
            adsearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer) (cn=" + computerHostName + "))";
            adsearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
            adsearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description");
            SearchResultCollection searchResults = adsearcher.FindAll();

            foreach (SearchResult searchResult in searchResults)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(searchResult.Properties["adspath"][0]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I modified it a little to give me the below, it now checks to see if a computer exists which is what I wanted:

```
DirectoryContext dirCtx = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, "domain.lan");
using (Domain usersDomain = Domain.GetDomain(dirCtx))
    using (DirectorySearcher adsearcher = new DirectorySearcher(usersDomain.GetDirectoryEntry()))
    {
        adsearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer) (cn=" + computerHostName + "))";
        adsearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        adsearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description");
        SearchResult searchResults = adsearcher.FindOne();

        if (searchResults.ToString().Length <= 0)
        {
            //nothing found
            Console.Write("Cannot find");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Found");
        }
    }
```

Thanks, everyone for your help :)